# Find differences across two datasets

Tags: sql, teradata, proc-sql

I would like to get information on users that are in a table but not in another one.
Sample of data:

```
Table_1
user1 user2 flag_ind
Ambra Burn    1
Ambra Downs   0
Chris Leopold 1
Martin Stewart 0



Table 2
user1 user2 flag_ind
Ambra Burn    0
Greg  See     1
Curtis John   0


Expected output

    user1 user2 
    Ambra Downs    
    Chris Leopold 
    Martin Stewart 
    Greg See
    Curtis John
```

I used a left join to get the differences between the two datasets. I would need to compare values of user1 from Table 1 and values of user1 from Table 2, as well as
values of user2 from Table 1 and values of user2 from Table 2 and get a final list.
Now, what I have found is a difference in the missing values when I use a left join vs. minus.
Could you help me to get the desired output and understand why left join and minus reproduce different values?

Thanks

Comment: If you've run some queries and the results are not as you expect them to be, it would definitely be useful if you include details of the queries in your question, that way people can help you to understand where you might be going astray, rather than either a) potentially trying to guess, or b) simply providing you with a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what you mean by left join minus. It's better that you can show your sql statements. But a solution could be follow:

```
(SELECT *
FROM Table_1
EXCEPT DISTINCT
SELECT *
FROM Table_2)

UNION DISTINCT

(SELECT *
FROM Table_2
EXCEPT DISTINCT
SELECT *
FROM Table_1)
```

The first part before UNION DISTINCT gives you what's in table_1 that's not in table_2.

The later part after UNION DISTINCT gives what's in table_2 that are not in table_1.

And you combine with UNION DISTINCT, you got what's differnece between the two tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can use merge in data step. First we generate input tables and sort them.

```
data table1;
    input user1 $ user2 $;
    datalines;
Ambra Burn
Ambra Downs
Chris Leopold
Martin Stewart
;
run;

data table2;
    input user1 $ user2 $;
    datalines;
Ambra Burn
Greg  See
Curtis John
;
run;

proc sort data=table1;
    by user1 user2;
run;

proc sort data=table2;
    by user1 user2;
run;
```

Then we merge tables using (In1+In2)=1 line - so either in one, or in the other, but not in both.

```
data want;
    merge table1(IN=In1) table2(IN=In2);
    by user1 user2;
    if (In1+In2)=1 then output;
run;
```

For more details I suggest [this](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings09/036-2009.pdf) article.